# Javascript scope in promises

Tags: javascript, scope

How can I access to the user object in the promises callback ?

I try to bind it with no success.

```
const promises = User.find(req.user._id).exec();
promises.then(function (user) {
  noAccessFunction().then(function (customer) {
    // HERE
    user.save();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Promises are not callbacks! Mutate it as if it were a chain of values. Maybe something like this:

```
const promises = User.find(req.user._id).exec();
promises.then(function (user) {
  return myfunction().then(function (customer) {
    return user.save();
  });
});
```

Promises can also be flattened:

```
const promises = User.find(req.user._id).exec();
promises.then(function (user) {
  return myfunction(user);
})
.then(function (customer) {
  return customer.save();
});
```

In any case the code above is speculation since you have not provided enough information as to what you want to happen.